# Office.js Word Add-in - How to manage test/prod versions of an Add-in manifest

Tags: ms-word, office365, office-js

## Summary

For some users, clicking our add-in icon on the ribbon will open a blank task pane. The icon appears to shift to the far right of the ribbon and clicking it again opens a second task pane that correctly loads the add-in, with the 1st still visible and still blank.

## Context

We suspect we are causing conflicts in the cache and are looking for advice on properly managing the manifests of a test version and a production version. So far, we have kept the 2 manifests exactly the same except for the URLs which point to different ports on a single server.

The users reporting this are mostly but not only our testers who had previously side-loaded the development version of the add-in manifest and have since installed the production version from the "ADMIN MANAGED" company store.

## Reproduction

We can repeat the behaviour on a Windows machine that had also previously side-loaded the add-in. First, we close Word and delete the "wef" folder. This effectively removes the Company store installed add-in icon from the ribbon once Word is restarted. Then, install the add-in from the company store. Immediately in the currently opened document the add-in icon appears on the ribbon and when clicked will open a single correctly functioning task pane. However, once Word is restarted again the issue is back and the behavior described above occurs.

## Your Environment

- Platform: PC desktop
- Host: Word
- Office version number: Word version 1808 (Build 10730.20155 Click-to-Run)
- Operating System: Windows 10

## Useful logs

### Add-in ribbon icon initial position

[image: Add-in ribbon icon initial position]

### Icon shifts right and opens blank task pane

[image: Icon shifts right and opens blank task pane]

### 2nd click opens 2nd task pane and correctly loads add-in

[image: 2nd click opens 2nd task pane and correctly loads add-in]

## GitHub Issue

https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/327

Answer (score 2):

yes this is effectively an issue of having the same add-in installed from multiple (independent) add-in catalogs (i.e. O365 centralized deployment and store and/or file share etc.)

and yes this should only happen to the universe of users who are in those conditions. At the time of shipping the feature this was considered an edge case. we are analyzing telemetry to undertstand the frequency of this issue.

for now, we recommend you to avoid such conditions and advise your users to keep the manifest from  Centralized deployment only.

ALso make sure to not deply this add-in to your dev team, on centralized deployment you can target specific users or groups to avoid such condition.

Comment: We have sent a blast email to all our users asking them if they are experiencing this issue. So far we have 29 respondents who have never sideloaded and only installed through central deployment.

Given this evidence, it seems there is a different root cause to this issue than having installed from multiple catalogs.

Is there any known workaround for this? We have tried deleting related registry items and every bit of cache-like files we could find. Is there anything else we can try? We're wondering where else is Word or Office hanging on to these Add-Ins?